# Set SQLite Database Location with DatabaseHelper

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

my plan is to create a database for my app that preserves even after uninstalling the application, so users won't need to insert all data again.
I found out you could change the location of the SQLite file, but didn't find any way to do it.

I'm using the `SQLiteOpenHelper` for my project.

Is there a way to define the location of the database?

Comment: When users uninstall an application probably they do it because they don't want it in their devices. If they do it so that they can reinstall for whatever reasons, it would be better to give them a backup/restore option inside the app, so they can restore the db after they reinstall.

Comment: Even better is an import/export option. Few users have any ability to work with a SQLite database. If, instead, you offer export options, you make it more likely that users can actually use the retained data. Whether that exported data is in some tabular format (e.g., CSV) or in some document format (e.g., HTML) would depend a bit on the data and how users might use it.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using the SQLiteOpenHelper for my project.

> Is there a way to define the location of the database?

**SQLiteOpenHelper** is designed to use the default path. You can always copy the file into the appropriate location (data/data/<the_package>/databases/<your_database_name>) before it is opened.

However, you can specify a path using the [SQLiteDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase)'s  `openDatabase` or `openOrCreateDatabase` methods (which is what SQLiteOpenHelper uses).